# R devtools build binary package from bitbucket

Tags: r, jenkins, build, package, bitbucket

I would like to create a Jenkins script to build a binary package from a bitbucket R repository.

I know the command `devtools::build(binary = TRUE, args = c('--preclean'))`.

How can I link this to my bitbucket repository to build from remote instead of locally?

Comment: the `pkg` argument "can be path or package name" - can the path point to your bitbucket?

Comment: @SymbolixAU doesn't work... how can I authenticate to my bitbucket account? it is a private repo.